# How can I create an entity specific to a user?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm creating an action for Google Assistant with Dialogflow and [`actions-on-google-nodejs`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) that accesses the [GitKraken Glo API](https://support.gitkraken.com/developers/api/#endpoint-documentation) to add cards to people's boards. I'm authenticating my users with Account Linking. I want my users to be able to say things like `Add a card to [board name]` or `Add a card`. If a board name isn't given I want the action to prompt the user for it. How can I create a session entity that get's all the board names for the logged in user?

> Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I'm pretty new to Actions on
>   Google and Dialogflow. Feel free to ask questions for clarity.

Comment: have you check this : https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#session_entities

Comment: @sid8491 Yes, I've checked it out. I'm not sure how to link it with my user though?

Comment: I think more than an entity specific for a user, you'd need a webhook to handle this, as you would be querying an external API to pull board names (I'm assuming?) Then, you'd be able to create an intent with a parameter that matches an item in the list

Comment: Do you have code that you're using now to get the boards for the user? Is the problem with the Account linking portion or the Session Entity portion? Where, exactly, is the problem you're running into?

Comment: @Prisoner My code is at https://github.com/nathfreder/gitkraken-glo

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to add a session entity with the user's boards. I use Account Linking to get an access token so I can receive the user's boards.

Comment: @Prisoner My goal is not not need to use `@sys.any` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you'll need to do first to use a Session Entity:

- The Entity Type needs to already exist. Session Entities update existing ones. The easiest way to do this is to create the Entity you want in the Dialogflow UI. It doesn't need to have any Entities in it, but having one as a default can be useful.
- You need a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for your project in Google Cloud that will do the update, and a secret key for this account.
- Your life will be a *lot* easier if you use a library, such as the [dialogflow-nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) library.

In general, your code needs to do the following, typically when the user first starts the session (ie - in your Welcome Intent Handler):

- Get the list of boards
- Update the Session Entity Type, creating an Entity for each board. Doing this update involves:

  - Issuing a [patch against the projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes/patch) method with a [SessionEntityType](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes#SessionEntityType) for the Entity Type you're overriding.
  - The [SessionEntityType](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes#SessionEntityType) will contain an array of [Entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/Entity) with the canonical name (likely the board name, or some unique identifier) and any aliases for it (at least the board name, possibly anything else, possibly including aliases like "the first one" or "the most recent one").

The README for the library includes links to sample code about how to do this using the nodejs library. Code that I have that does this work has a function like this:

```
function setSessionEntity( env, entityType ){
  const config = envToConfig( env );
  const client = new dialogflow.SessionEntityTypesClient( config );

  let parent = env.dialogflow.parent;
  if( entityType.displayName && !entityType.name ){
    entityType.name = `${parent}/entityTypes/${entityType.displayName}`;
  }
  if( !entityType.entityOverrideMode ){
    entityType.entityOverrideMode = 'ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE';
  }

  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    sessionEntityType: entityType
  };
  return client.createSessionEntityType( request );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it! I was really confused.

Comment: Glad this helps!

Comment: What if the user doesn't go through the default welcome intent? e.g. "Hey Google, ask app to add a card to [board]"?

Comment: This is a chicken and egg problem. {: You need to do the match before you have the user, but you can' because you didn't get the user yet. For deep linking intents such as this, I still need a routine that locates a board by name. If you really want, you could have your fulfillment call the intent with the Detect Intent API. Open a new question if you want to explore this option further.

Answer (score 0):

## conv.user.email

You can use [conv.user](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.user.html) object :

```
const Users = {};

app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const email = conv.user.email
    Users[email] = { };
    conv.ask(`I got your email as ${email}. What do you want to do next?`)
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to next?`)
  }
})

app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    Users[conv.user.email] = {
      lastinput: input
    };
  }
});
```

## conv.id

Also with conv id is unique id for the current conversation.

```
// Create an app instance
const app = dialogflow()

// Register handlers for Dialogflow intents

const Users = {};

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
   Users[conv.id] = {
       conversationId: conv.id,
       name: '1234'
   };
})

app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
   Users[conv.id] = {
       lastinput: input
   };
});

app.intent('Goodbye', conv => {
  delete Users[conv.id];
})
```

Comment: I don’t think this explains my issue. I want to do stuff with session entities but I don’t know how to tie it into account linking.